# Is it possible to have a multiclass SVM as the last layer of a CNN using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, svm

I would like to use a multiclass RBF SVM as the last layer of my CNN model built in Tensorflow.

I have currently got the following. But instead of the last layer, is it possible to slip an SVM in?
What are my options. 
I found that Tensorflow have something called Random Fourier Features where I can use kernel methods to mimic an SVM? Is this an option? If so how would I go about implementing it into what I currently have?

```
net = x_noisy_image

# 1st convolutional layer.
net = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=net, name='layer_conv1', padding='same',
                       filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# 2nd convolutional layer.
net = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=net, name='layer_conv2', padding='same',
                       filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# Pooling layer
net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=net, pool_size=2, strides=2)

# 3rd convolutional layer.
net = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=net, name='layer_conv3', padding='same',
                       filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# 4th convolution layer
net = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=net, name='layer_conv4', padding='same',
                       filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# Pooling layer
net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=net, pool_size=2, strides=2)

# Flatten layer.This should eventually be replaced by:
# net = tf.layers.flatten(net)
net = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(net)

# 1st fully-connected / dense layer.
net = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, name='layer_fc1',
                      units=200, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# 2nd fully-connected / dense layer.
net = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, name='layer_fc2',
                      units=200, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# 3rd fully-connected / dense layer.
net = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, name='layer_fc_out',
                      units=num_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax)



# Unscaled output of the network.
logits = net
# Softmax output of the network.
y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)
# Loss measure to be optimized.
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_true,
                                                           logits=logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

"""
Optimizer for Normal Training
"""
[var.name for var in tf.trainable_variables()]
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about multiclass SVM but I do know about linear SVM and in order to do that you should change your activation to linear and loss to hinge. Check this link to get clarification https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/quasi_svm/